# Android YoutubePlayer stops with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: us" exception and app crashes

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Unable to play video in Android using YoutubePlayerActivity and the app crashes when video gets loaded with error"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: us" The thumbnail of video also is not getting loaded in this scenario

This is happening only for some of the videos and sometimes the videos are playing fine.. Inconsistency with this

log file:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: us
     at up.<clinit>(SourceFile:145)
     at ixc.e(SourceFile:250)
     at bqf.run(SourceFile:74)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: same problem here :(

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8044&q=label%3AAPi-YouTube%20java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A%20us&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) it's related to display videos with Ads